# start/stop websocket server from php exec()

Tags: php, websocket, cpanel, centos7, whm

I'm trying to run and control a websocket process from php.

My server is a VPS with cpanel and WHM.

I follow this tutorial: http://www.techzonemind.com/php-websocket-library-two-way-real-time-communication/

and it run fine when started the server in CLI.

Then, problem occurred when using PHP shell_exec() to start the websocket script

```
shell_exec('nohup php public_html/stage/chat/instantchat/server.php > output.log 2>&1 > output2.log &');
```

I checked the process manager in WHM, the server.php process PID keep changing and chat client can't connect and I can't kill the process.

Anyone have idea why?

Comment: can't help you, since there's no useful information here, like actual code or error messages.

Comment: @MarcB this is the code: <?php shell_exec('nohup php public_html/stage/chat/instantchat/server.php > output.log 2>&1 > output2.log &'); ?> and there is no error message.

Comment: Have you checked your `output.log`/`output2.log`? What's in your server.php? It's very difficult to guess at what's happening without seeing code.